# Spinnaker:There is no stage type to be selected

Tags: spinnaker

After I deploy the Spinnaker with the command './InstallSpinnaker.sh' on https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker, but when I create the Pipeline and add stage ,I found there is no stage type to be selected, would you help on it ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remember this was the option for spinnaker as a dev deployment option on `localdebian`

Please install in a Kubernetes cluster or get easily started with [Minnaker](https://github.com/armory/minnaker)
thanks